# Proving ${n + 2 \choose m + 1} = {n \choose m + 1} + 2{n \choose m} + {n \choose m - 1}$ using the Binomial Theorem

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I want to prove the following identity using the Binomial Theorem:
$${n + 2 \choose m + 1} = {n \choose m + 1} + 2{n \choose m} + {n \choose m - 1}$$

I have a combinatorial solution: Suppose we want to choose $m + 1$ people among $n + 2$ people where 2 of these people are children. This can be done in ${n + 2 \choose m}$ ways. Now to prove the identity we count this differently by looking at the different cases: pick no children, pick 1 child, pick 2 children.

But I want to prove this using the Binomial Theorem but I have no idea how this can be done. I only know that ${n + 2 \choose m + 1}$ is the coefficient of $x^{m + 1}y^{n + 1 - m}$ in $(x + y)^{n + 2}$ but I haven't been able to do anything with this. I tried different values of $x$ and $y$ and taking derivatives but I couldn't solve the problem.

Hints would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773742/using-the-binomial-identity-prove-that-n-choose-k2n-choose-k1n-choose) question is pretty much the same as mine, however there are no solutions using the Binomial theorem there.

Comment: @DiegoMath No, none of the solutions used the binomial theorem. I will edit my question and state this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand $(x+y)^n$ and $(x+y)^2$ separately, then multiply the two expansions together.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $[x^k]f(x)$ denote the $x^k$ coefficient in $f(x)$ so$$\binom{n+2}{m+1}=[x^{m+1}](1+x)^{n+2}=[x^{m+1}](1+x)^n(1+2x+x^2).$$(In other words, what @Arthur said, but we only need the case $y=1$.)

Comment: (I used $y$ rather than 1 because that's what the OP did.)